# Do questions by high-rep users get fewer answers?

Tags: discussion, reputation, answers

When I was a new user, I asked a question and got lots of answers. I just recently asked a question and got no answers -- only intelligent comments. Why am I not getting answers anymore now that I've got more reputation?

Comment: There was not a single complete sentence in your question...

Comment: If all your questions look like this, I can tell why no one answers. You probably haven't given then enough information to answer it properly.

Comment: maybe people are afraid of sounding stupid; if your reputation is so much higher than theirs, they may feel as if they're not qualified to answer.

Comment: 593 rep is hardly high...

Comment: you can lead a horse to water, but you can't make him drink...

Answer (score 10):

There are several reasons for not getting answers. Possibilities include:

- If you don't have a high accept rate, that disinclines some people from answering (not everyone though; I rarely look at the accept rate)
- If you ask a question no-one knows the answer to, then obviously it'll be hard to get answers
- There are few other people who have experience in the relevant field, and they happen not to see your question
- Your question is asked badly

Of these options, I'd say that the last is *by far* the most common reason for a lack of answers. I have a [guide to asking questions well](http://tinyurl.com/so-hints) - do your questions meet the suggestions in that guide?

Answer (score 9):

587 reputation probably isn't enough to dissuade people from answering; maybe your question is just unclear. You've asked 8 questions in the last two days and 7 have gotten answers, so I assume you're talking about [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4169078/binding-formview-dynamically-is-not-working). Somebody asked for clarification and you left a sarcastic reply without answering -- maybe you should actually answer that comment and see if it helps? Or maybe it just happens that nobody knows the answer; [16 unanswered questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user:287745+answers:0) out of 158 asked isn't bad